# jOOQ Map Record from raw SQL to Pojos

Tags: sql, jooq

I have two tables with a one to many relationship, lets say they are `row` and `columns`, where a row can have many columns.

Using jOOQ (3.12.3) I can perform the following query:

```
    Map<JooqRowPojo, List<JooqColumnPojo>> join = dslContext.select()
    .from(ROW).join(COLUMN).onKey(Keys.COLUMN__ROW_ID__FK)
    .fetchAsync().thenApply(r -> {
      return r.intoGroups(r1 -> r1.into(ROW).into(JooqRowPojo.class),
          r1 -> r1.into(COLUMN).into(JooqColumnPojo.class));
    }).toCompletableFuture().join();
```

This returns the rows I expect mapped into Pojos as I expect.

However, if I try the above with raw SQL:

```
dslContext.fetch("SELECT * FROM row JOIN column ON row.row_id = column.row_id")
  .intoGroups(r1 -> r1.into(ROW).into(JooqRowPojo.class),
              r1 -> r1.into(COLUMN).into(JooqColumnPojo.class))
```

What I get is a bunch of PoJo instances where all values are `null` and not the values from the table. I'm not sure why I can't map the records from the raw sql?

N.B. This is a simplified example with the behaviour I have observed, in practice I need to run a complicated query that cannot be expressed in the JOOQ API/DSL.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. How do JooqRowPojo and JooqColumnPojo look like?

Comment: They are POJOs generated by jOOQ with the following config:
```
                            <pojos>true</pojos>
                            <immutablePojos>true</immutablePojos>
                            <jpaAnnotations>true</jpaAnnotations>
                            <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                            <pojosEqualsAndHashCode>true</pojosEqualsAndHashCode>```

Are you using 3.12.3?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't reproduce your problem. Could you provide your example on GitHub?

Comment: Sure - may I ask you share your working example here so I can see if I can figure out what's different?

Comment: https://github.com/72services/vaadin-erp checkout JooqTest

Comment: While there is no inherent reason for *all values* to be `null` in the second case, the second case does provide jOOQ with less type information. Depending on whether JDBC `ResultSetMetaData` can provide appropriately qualified columns or not, it may be impossible to disambiguate column names that are shared between the two tables. You would see a warning in the logs in this case.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I think the issue must be related to Postgres, I can run your project and the test pass but if I take the same tables and code over to my project with Postgres then the issue appears.